# rsyslogd not monitoring all files in config file

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rsyslog

I am not seeing rsyslog pick up all files I am trying to monitor.  I am using the standard config from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but am adding the contents below to /etc/rsyslog.d/30-logentries.conf.

I only see messages from /var/log/myapp.log and a few system log files that are monitored in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf being pushed to LogEntries, not the other files I am trying to monitor.

I've verified the following:

- My other log files are world readable
- My other log files are being written to
- LogEntries is receiving log messages from the server
- /var/log/syslog sees what LogEntries sees, so the log messages don't appear to be lost by log entries
- Restarting rsyslog doesn't fix the issue

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ModLoad imfile   # Load the imfile input module
$ModLoad imklog   # for reading kernel log messages
$ModLoad imuxsock # for reading local syslog messages

$InputFileName /var/log/myapp.log
$InputFileTag myapp:
$InputFileStateFile myapp
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/myapp.log
$InputFileTag nginx-myapp:
$InputFileStateFile nginx-myapp
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/access.log
$InputFileTag nginx-access:
$InputFileStateFile nginx-access
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/error.log
$InputFileTag nginx-error:
$InputFileStateFile nginx-error
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/redir-to-http-myapp.log
$InputFileTag nginx-redir-to-http-myapp:
$InputFileStateFile nginx-redir-to-http-myapp
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/redir-to-www-myapp.log
$InputFileTag nginx-redir-to-www-myapp:
$InputFileStateFile nginx-redir-to-www-myapp
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFilePollInterval 1

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/syslog.logentries.crt
$ActionSendStreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.logentries.com

$template LogentriesFormat,"guidguid-guid-guid-guid-guidguidguid production %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
*.* @@api.logentries.com:20000;LogentriesFormat
```

Comment: Of course right after I post to Serverfault I figure it out.  Even though the ngnix log *files* were world readable, the ngnix log *directory* was not.  

Giving rsyslog access to that directory fixed it.

Hope this saves someone time!

I'll post as an answer after 8 hours - rep isn't high enough to do it now.

Comment: Hey Dylan, feel like posting that formal answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Unicorn(s) was converting comment to CW....</sub>

To get rsyslog process the file, its file must be readable by rsyslog. Even though the nginx log files were world readable, the nginx log directory (`/var/log/nginx/`) was not. Giving rsyslog access to that directory fixed it.